# Start KDE 5 through VNC

Tags: kde, remote-desktop, vnc, plasma

I am trying to setup TightVNC so that I can access my KDE Plasma 5 desktop remotely.

Problem is, I don't know what to put in the `~/.vnc/xstartup` file to start KDE.

Comment: SDDM login manager appears to kick off using the `/usr/bin/startkde` script (as seen in `/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop`). Perhaps try that one. Will make this an answer if that works.

Comment: When I tried this, KWin (in the VNC viewer) crashed. Same with `plasmashell`.